Pebble template engine - check if includable .peb file exists
My code includes sub template according to product SKU:
 {% if ["GB01","GB02","GB03","GB04","GB05"] contains product.attributes.sku %}
    {% include 'products/_custom_jumbtron_' +  product.attributes.sku  + '.peb' %}
  {% else %}
    {% include 'products/_custom_jumbtron.peb' %}
  {% endif %}

Right now, this solution has problems: If SKU is in array but the sub template file doesn't exist, I get an error or includable file exist, but the product SKU is not in array, then it falls to default one.
Is it possible in Pebble template file to control if the includable file exists and if not then fall back to default one?

It seems this is a (subset) of Twig. You could try by doing the following {% include [ 'products/_custom_jumbtron_' +  product.attributes.sku  + '.peb', 'default.peb', ] %} - This behavior will include the first existing template in the array, so if the first template doesn't exist the default.peb will be used a fallback. - Reference (at the  bottom)

FYI: You probably need to use ~ and not + for string concatenations
